# How to get img src form its alt?

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I want to parse an HTML web page by PHP DomDocument and extract img from its alt attribute. A function like `getElementById()`. Is there any way for do it?

Comment: The alt attribute is usually a description of the image. If you can access the alt attribute then you can access the src attribute which is the image path and name.

Answer (score 1):

DOMDocument has method called getElementsByTagName which can be used to get element by tag name . For example

```
    <?php
    $htmlStr = <<<EOD
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Some nice page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>Something nice</h1>
    <img id="beautiful-para" src="https://" alt="foo-hj" />

    </body>
    </html>
    EOD;

    $doc = new DomDocument;

    $doc->validateOnParse = true;
    $doc->loadHTML($htmlStr);
   $images = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

  foreach ($images as $image) {
      var_dump($image->getAttribute('alt'));
   }
```

This would give

```
string(6) "foo-hj"
```

Hope this helps.